# Perumations of size N java Array

Tags: java, arrays, algorithm, permutation

In c++ permutations of an array can be generated using the function `next_permutation`. Is there a java equivalent of such a function to generate permutations of a size N array?

I am trying to come up with an equivalent recursive implementation but am struggling to solidify my logic.

Comment: [std::next_permutation](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/next_permutation) provides possible (C++) implementation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There isn't a built-in function like this in java. You'll have to create your own, which is not that complicated. I'll provide an edit to this answer momentarily with a solution (not necessarily the best solution)

```
public static void printperms(int[] perm, boolean[] used, int k)
{
    if (k == perm.length) print(perm);
    for (int i=0; i<perm.length; i++) {
        if (!used[i]) {
           used[i] = true;
           perm[k] = i;
           printperms(perm, used, k+1);
           used[i] = false;
        }
    }
}
```

you can then create a new method, like so, to call it:

```
public void perms(int n){
    printperms(new int[n], new boolean[n], 0);
}
```

Lastly, where I have the `print` method, you can have the Array added to a list instead so that you can collect them all in a list, or you can just print it out. Your choice. Do with it as you please.

Comment: You have to implement your own function, just try by yourself and if you feel any problem share your code, we will here to help you. You mat get help from https://www.baeldung.com/java-array-permutations